# C# Converting object to byte array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, serialization, deserialization

I'm making a chat system thing with tcp which requires to send things in byte arrays, but when I convert an image into a byte array, send it and then convert back it gives this error: 'End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed.'. With strings it works just fine.

```
    public byte[] ObjectToByteArray(object obj)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, obj);
            return stream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public object ByteArrayToObject(byte[] bytes)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            stream.Position = 0;
            var obj = binForm.Deserialize(stream);
            return obj;
        }
    }
```

Comment: When wending data you the receiving side of a connection always need to know where the data ends.  So you either send fixed length messages, terminate a message with a terminator (not part of message), or precede each message with a byte count.  A transfer protocol usually has two layers 1) Application Layer 2) Transport Layer.  Your code only has one layer.  A chat application your brain can figure out where each message ends.  An application you have to add what your brain does in code.

Answer (score 2):

There's two separate things here; firstly, and I **cannot emphasize this enough**; do not use `BinaryFormatter`. Ever. It *will* hurt you. Lots of serializers exist, and `BinaryFormatter` (and the cousin `NetDataContractSerializer`) is literally the *absolute last* you should use. I can expand on that if you like, or I can suggest alternatives if you like.

Now; as for the actual problem: I strongly suspect that it isn't what you think it is. I have a hunch, based on decades of working on network code, that the *real* problem here is "framing". By which I mean: TCP is a stream protocol, not a message/packet protocol. I strongly suspect that you have not correctly deframed the exact bytes that were sent. I can't say this for sure without seeing your socket code, but... as I say: it is an hunch based on lots of experience. To investigate this: note the length of the bytes you send, and note the length of the bytes you've received. I'm pretty sure you'll find they are different. If there's still doubt: get the base-64 or hex string of the sent payload and the received payload (`Convert.ToBase64String`, for example), and compare that string. I'm pretty sure they'll turn out to be different.

Ultimately, network code is *hard*; I could try and explain individual points, but "how to correctly send messages over a network" could fill a book. IMO, if you're not interested in specializing in writing network code for the next 5 years: use an existing tool that will do the job for you, for example gRPC. Lots and lots of other messaging RPC tools exist.

Comment: I tried the Convert.ToBase64String function but this just returns a string, I need to send an object. The only thing I could find that can do this was the BinaryFormatter which I know isn't great. I also really don't want to use external dlls which would make it way too complicated in my opinion. Also I use the functions that are in the question on both server side and client side just incase you wanted to know

Comment: @GHOST you misunderstand me; my mention of `Convert.ToBase64String` is **just to check whether you received the exact same bytes that you sent**, since it is very easy to compare strings, even by eye in a text editor. My intention was not for that to replace your existing serialization. Re the code in the question: unless I can see how you wrote and read that `byte[]` re the network - then that code (which I agree looks like it should work, by itself) doesn't tell me much.

Comment: @GHOST re external dlls complicating things.... well, that's massively subjective; I hear what you're saying, although personally I'm not sure how adding a NuGet package reference is inconvenient (since everything else just works), but: that's up to you. All I can say is: [you have been warned](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2020/03/why-do-i-rag-on-binaryformatter.html) (note the real details there are in the "I present my thesis" link)

Comment: Yea I had that exact thing before with serializing classes which hold the object, but it does require a dll. I want the exe to be easily sent over as an exe, this is also one of the many reasons why I don't want any dlls. I also tried ILMerge to merge the dll into the exe file but that also failed

Comment: @GHOST it sounds like what you *actually* want here is a "single file deployment" - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file - then how that functionality is composed becomes not your problem

Comment: I ditched the part where I don't use any libraries. I'm now using json to send things over, but the images still won't send over properly, I've spent about 4 hours debugging this and it seems to come down to the socket not sending the data properly. If I compare the json that the client sends to the thing that the server receives its completely different, I thought it was a problem with the encoding to the byte array since I used Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes() and GetString(), but when I changed it to UTF8 it had the exact same problem, I think sockets are incompatible with some characters.

Comment: @GHOST no, sockets are not incompatible with some characters; sockets don't even see characters, they see bytes; personally I'd have used protobuf, but JSON should be fine here. I can guarantee you: sockets are not broken, and the error is in your code. If you want me to help you with that, I can  certainly find the problem (network programming is a speciality), but I can't do that without being able to see code.

Comment: Here is a download to the source code https://www.dropbox.com/s/cmc7bttx1vo3h8c/TCPClientAndServer.zip?dl=0
it contains tcp client and server

Comment: @GHOST so yes, I was absolutely right; the problem is "framing"; you can't just `.[Begin|End]Receive` data and expect it to line up conveniently with messages; TCP is a stream protocol, not a message protocol; to explain what I mean, please see the "Network packets: what you send is not (usually) what you get" section [here](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html). However; I cannot emphasize enough: this is *hard stuff*; if you aren't 100% sure what you're doing, it would be a lot less work to just use a pre-rolled messaging library, for example:

Comment: @GHOST gRPC is pretty trivial to get working, works on .NET Framework or .NET Core / etc - [Getting Started guide is here](https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net.Grpc/gettingstarted) (using protobuf-net.Grpc, for code-first usage, but there's also a Google-owned contract-first version) - but: there are lots of available messaging implementations to choose from, all of which will solve *for you* a whole bunch of problems that you don't yet know exist; otherwise, you're just going to be running from problem to problem; there are a **lot** of things to consider on networked systems

Comment: currently I have the system in async, i think i can turn it into a synced system. That'll probably work. Also the reason I'm doing this blindly is because I want to learn this kind of networking, I used to do this exact thing in Scratch (the kids programming language) when I was 12, now im 15 and try to do it in here. I'll take a look at some other libraries for this, also thank you for all your help with this project.